# Exception trying to Authenticate Graph Client on Azure Publish: "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I'm trying to authenticate The Microsoft Graph API with ADAL and getting the following exception when I publish to Azure:

> "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"

It works fine when I run locally.

```
        public GraphServiceClient GetAuthGraphClient()
        {

        string graphResourceID = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";

        return new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                string accessToken = await GetTokenForApplication(graphResourceID);
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
            }
            ));

        }
        public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication(string graphResourceID)
        {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
        string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

        try {
            // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, UserIdentifier.AnyUser);
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                // Capture error for handling outside of catch block
                ErrorMessage = e.Message;

            return null;
        }

    }
```

**Update** 
Per @Fei Xue I have updated my code to the below:

```
    public string GetTokenForApplication(string graphResourceID)
    {
    string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
    string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID;


    try {
        // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
        ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred).Result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        return null;
    }

    }
    public GraphServiceClient GetAuthGraphClient()
    {
    string graphResourceID = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";

    return new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            string accessToken =  GetTokenForApplication(graphResourceID);
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        ));
    }
```

The following is the output so I think It's returning token successfully now:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : 6/20/2017 12:23:36 PM: 29c5558f-e33b-4312-b235-612909ac1309 - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
    Access Token Hash: <a long access token>
    Refresh Token Hash: [No Refresh Token]
    Expiration Time: 6/20/2017 1:23:34 PM +00:00
    User Hash: null
```

However, now, I don't think I'm getting the user profile correctly.  Is this correct?

```
public void GetUserProfile(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    this.User = Task.Run(async () => { return await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); }).Result;
}
```

Because the User property of my Viewmodel is not getting any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method try to acquire token from cache or refresh the access token using refresh token.

If you were developing a service, you can consider using the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) to authenticate with Azure AD. Here is the code for your reference:

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";

string clientId = "";
string secret = "";
string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";

var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential).Result.AccessToken;
```

In-addition, please ensure that you have config the enough permission to call the corresponding the Microsoft Graph REST. You can refer the link below about the detailed permission:

[Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference)

Comment: Thank you Fei Xue!  I have updated my post above to show what happens after updating my code to your suggestion.  It looks like it's getting an access token successfully now.  I also have enough permissions to call the Graph REST.

Comment: @ProperNouns If the rely is helpful to resolve the issue, please accept it as answer so that other communities who have the same issue could recognize the solution easily.

Comment: Xue, I have marked as the correct answer.  Please see my update above.  Am I calling the user profile correctly?  Should I ask this in another question?

Comment: The token acquiring using the client credential will not work for this rest since there is no user context in this kind of token. Normally, it used in a daemon service.  Based on the code, it seems that you were calling the Microsoft Graph REST in a web app. If I understood correctly, you need to acquire the token using the **code grant flow**. You can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) about this scenario. If you still have the problem, I suggest that you reopen a new thread since this post is not describe the problem clearly.

Comment: Will do, I've created another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44722002/calling-graph-api-through-viewmodel-in-mvc-web-app)